# Nested routes and dot in url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controller

I'm building a simple todo app for some practice.  I have projects which has_many tasks and tasks belongs_to projects.

So that I can display url/projects/1/tasks I'm nesting the route:

routes.rb

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
```

In my project show view I have the following form:

```
Add a task:
<%= form_for [@project, @task] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :Task_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Task Name" %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create Task' %>
<% end %>
```

In my tasks controller I'm doing the following:

```
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.new(params[:task])
    if @task.save
      redirect_to projects_path(@project)
    else
      redirect_to projects_path(@project)
    end
  end
```

It seems on task.save when I redirect and pass in the project instance variable it redirects me to http://todoapp.dev/projects.5  (5 being the id of the project) instead of http://todoapp.dev/projects/5.

Could the problem be in my controller with the redirect_to method or possibly the nested route?

I have a basic understanding of Rails routing but could use some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the redirect_to in my controller I was using the pluralized version of the path. projects_path(@project) instead of project_path(@project).

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.new(params[:task])
    if @task.save
      redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
      redirect_to project_path(@project)
    end
  end
```

This ended up working.